# Best way of structuring .JS in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Since jQuery Mobile's method changePage will load only the  element with the data-role="page" attribute set, I am not able to use external .js files in my project.

A couple workarounds I've come across:

- Load all the .js at once in the first page. It works perfectly, I can use events when each page loads and have it structured on different .js files. It doesn't look right to me though.
- Use  tags within the data-role="page" div. It works too, but I don't know how "elegant" is to insert  in random places in the HTML.
- Use jQuery to load it asynchronously. I would make a request as the new page loads. Drawback: not so elegant either and generates two requests.

I couldn't find any information on this matter in the documentation. What solution is considered the best one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generally accepted approach seems to be to use a build script (such as a Node.js jakefile https://github.com/mde/jake) to build a 'production' copy of your web app where the scripts it requires are all aggregated into one and minified.

Dynamic loading of JS files is possible with hacks but I don't believe its generally worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Dont think alot of people have got onto the jqmobile band wagon yet hence the lack of documentation. I would take a look at a gallery like http://www.jqmgallery.com/ and look at peoples source.

Look at what http://m.twitpolls.com/ has done in comparison to most of the others. They have aggregated and abridged all css/js files. This has to be your best option.

Your later points/options dont sound too good to be honest.